# Is it possible to make clipboard work always the same?

Tags: clipboard

IIRC, once upon I time I used only the mouse for copy-and-paste, which I consider way superior to the Windows-like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> complication. Now after many years I'm slowly starting to use Linux again and to my horror I see that it doesn't work anymore, except between Emacs and terminal windows. Of course, the keyboard shortcuts don't work in Emacs, so it's a real pain e.g. to copy from Emacs to Firefox.

Is there a way how to fix it? **I mean I want to use marking and pasting using the mouse only everywhere, not the other way round.**

<sup>I'm not asking about clipboard managers, I need neither clipboard persistence nor multiple clipboards, but if it solves my problem, I'll go for it.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure what you have done with your specific set up, but this still works in everything I've just tried.

Comment: @Ward I'm using quite a new installation and did about nothing yet. I've marked a line in Emacs using a triple click, switched to Firefox, pressed the middle mouse button and nothing happened.

Comment: **Now it works...** I noticed my middle mouse button doesn't work sometimes... it must have been the reason. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the mouse

Kubuntu comes with a clipboard manager by default, [Klipper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/klipper).

Ubuntu has a simple clipboard manager (not installed by default) that does contains everything you want: no persistence and copy on select (configurable). It's called [Parcellite](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/parcellite). You need to enable "Use Primary (Selection)" to enable copy-on-select.

[image: Parcellite Preferences]

Both applications can be configured to (not) save the clipboard on shutdown.

---

#### Using the keyboard

In the terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT kill signal to applications.

The default shortcuts in the Terminal are:

- Copy: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- Paste: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

These shortcuts can be customized in the Terminal application itself.

Comment: Sorry, I see question wasn't clear enough. I don't want to use keyboard at all (when holding the mouse already).

Comment: @maartinus: updated, I'll add screenshots soon.

Answer (score 1):

In X you just have to mark the text you want to have copied and use the middle mouse button to paste it wherever you want.

Comment: This doesn't work e.g. for the URL in Firefox. I've tried it several times.

Comment: This is strange. Me and someone else tested this on 10.10 using Firefox 3.6.15 and 4 RC1. Both times it worked.

Comment: @maaartinus When you try pasting a URL into Firefox, how are you clearing the address bar first? I can select text in GNOME Terminal and then paste it into Firefox's address bar using the middle mouse button (and vice versa), but I don't know of a quick way to clear the address bar prior to pasting that doesn't involve selecting the current URL — an action that would overwrite my clipboard contents.

Comment: @ændrük The only workaround I know is to open a new tab instead of working in the same tab.